# Is spring data mongodb ready for production

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've seen spring data documentation and tried a little demo app. I like it because its easy to use. Mongodb and spring data is still arguably quite new technology so I'm worried of its maturity, although I fell in love with its philosophy.
I know I'm asking very relative question, but still some opinion and experience sharing will be appreciated:

- How likely will spring data mongodb continue to be developed, instead of being dumped like Spring Riak
- How buggy is the spring data? and how quickly does it get fixed?
- How big is the trend of spring data mongodb, is there any serious big production apps developed in this stack?

Answer (score 4):

I have used spring-data with mongodb in multiple applications. All of them are live and are customer facing applications. I cannot disclose the name.

I have not faced any bug with spring data till now.